# Memory leak on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ram

After one day my memory usage goes up to 91%. gnome-shell is part of the problem, but it seems like other programs are also holding memory as well. I am using the nouveau driver because Nvidia will not load the gdm hangs on boot with Nvidia. I have 8 gigs of memory and the Nvidia card is

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001082sv000010DEsd00000873bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF110 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti OEM]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Both drivers for Nvidia hang up and the I am not sure where to go on the memory leak.

Any ideas would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: If you are *telling* the world that you have discovered and verified a real memory leak, then this is the wrong place - the bug tracker is the right place. Many hangs and crashes are not due to memory leaks at all.

Comment: Unused memory is used for file/disk buffers... so the memory should show full utilization. What is the actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: The computer slows down and the system monitor shows anywhere from 91% to 98% memory utilization and runs painfully slow. After a fresh reboot system monitor shows around 17% memory utilization. Gnome-shell increases in size from 133 Mb to upwards of 400 Mb. This happens even if the computer sits idle for any period of time. The other problem is trying to install Nvidia hangs on GDM when booting.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting plex media server corrected the problem. However, now I have to figure out why plex media server keeps eating memory.